# VB.NET - MsDb2 query duration

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, db2

I don't know if that question will have a logic answer, or an answer at all but I cannot find one on Google, here or by myself.

I'm working for a client and interact directly with database for the first time for the last 5 months.

To interact with the database, we use web services from applications.

As I was passing most of my test successfully, but now I'm facing "Operation time-out" more and more sometimes, and nothing at other time.

I tried to test those methods from my web service directly to see what request take times or what part of my function was long enough to raise a timeout.

To sum up my situation, I have a list of name and need to retrieve their codes in my database. An example of a situation I'm facing, a simple select :

```sql
SELECT CODE FROM TABLE
WHERE NAME = @name
AND ACTIVE = 'Y'
```

When I find a value, it takes between 3 to 500 ms, which is a huge duration (I guess). On the other hand, when I don't find value, it takes between 1 to 4 ms in the best case, which is not a little thing considering the fact I'm looking for 7000 differents `name` at minimum, and have only 120 values found.

If we do the math, it is not a big deal, but kind of because, with a timeout at 30 sec, my query takes between 12 to 27 seconds, and more in a worst case.

What I try to ask you, is a possible reason for those differences.

Comment: Ask the Db2 DBA (if there is one) to examine the access-plan for your query. If it is a frequently used query or vital to performance then it should be fully indexed, and the isolation level should be optimal.  This is an administration question.

Comment: I finally got my answer. Those latences came from the Db2 driver who cause some issue on query duration.

Comment: You should then post the solution.   What dirver type you was using,  its version,  what APAR you hit,  and what you have done to fix it.  Purpose of this forum is sharing solutions so others in the future could benefit from it,  if they faces same or similar issue.

Comment: Actually, I was still looking for those details but it appears that my client cannot share those informations with me.. I'll post a version of my solution ASAP